# How to create Sub Type Class of Type Class in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Can we create `Sub Type` of `Type Class` in `haskell`? Up to how many level `sub-typing` of `Type Class` can go?

Comment: Yes, we can. By using type constraints. As for the level, I don't think there is a hard limit.

Comment: Note that a "sub type class" in the Haskell sense is not like a sub class in an OO language, all you can do is require any instance of the "sub type class" to also implement the type class (which is done with a type constraint as in the answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create some kind of subclass in Haskell. It looks basically like this:

```
class Parent a where
    ...

class Parent a => Child a where
    ...
```

Then any instance of `Child` is also required to be an instance of `Parent`.

See, for example, [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative) class.

Also I don't think there is a restriction on 'level' of subclassing since (I guess so) subclassing can be though as sequential union of corresponding instances' class dictionaries
which contain their respective implementations of polymorphic functions, and seemingly there are no boundaries for this dictionary growth.